# ¿Cómo puedo grabar en objetos los datos que obtengo recorriendo un archivo de texto con delimitador pipe "|"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Buen día compañeros,

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, estoy tratando de *parsear* un archivo de texto delimitado por *pipes* `|`, no es un CSV como tal ya que no tiene encabezados y cada fila tiene diferente tamaño y número de columnas, lo estoy tratando de hacer con la gema **CSV**; ya logré que identifique según el inicio de línea a que arreglo debo asignarlo, sin embargo conforme tengo las líneas en diferentes arreglos, debo asignar estos valores a diferentes variables para *parsear* el archivo y trasladarlo a otra clase.

El archivo de texto tiene esta forma:

```
E01|CFACE|A1|1002|1||2018-09-30|ORIGINAL||||1234578-7|16|C.F.|CONSUMIDOR FINAL||CIUDAD|||||||||GTQ|1|1||0.00|0||50.51|0.00|471.53|CUATROCIENTOS SETENTA Y UN QUETZAL(ES) 53/100 M.N|COMPARTAMOS1.4|C.F.

D01||C_GRUPAL_CM_GT|INTERESES DEVENGADOS CRÉDITO MUJER|1|S|UNITARIO|471.53|0.00|0.00|471.53|0.00|421.02|50.51

D02|IVA|421.02|50.51|12

I01|IVA|421.02|50.51|12

T01|1002|1002|1|test.TXT
```

Como pueden ver cada fila tiene diferente estructura y, adicional, entre cada una de ellas existe un salto de línea; estas se pueden repetir N veces, ya que cada juego de estas a excepto de la que inicia en `T01` es un documento compuesto por encabezado, detalles e impuestos, **mi problema es al asignar los valores que ya tengo en los arreglos a sus respectivas variables de un objeto de otra clase**, la forma como actualmente lleno los arreglos es a través de un `if`:

```
require 'csv'

class ConversionTxtMegaprint

    #Método para parsear los TXT
    def procesar_archivo (archivo)

        Rails.logger.debug "================================= INICIO ARCHIVO ===================================="
        Rails.logger.debug ""
        Rails.logger.debug "---> NOMBRE ARCHIVO: " + archivo
        Rails.logger.debug ""

        encabezado = Array.new
        detalle_descripcion = Array.new
        detalle_impuestos = Array.new
        impuestos = Array.new
        documento_origen = Array.new
        totales = Array.new

        # Se crea el objeto dteparser para establecer los valores del documento (cabecera y detalle), los datos
        # para llenar este objeto se tomaran del hash que es donde esta reunida toda la informacion.
        dteparser = DteParser.new
        # Se crea un nuevo objeto por cada detalle que encuentre relacionado al documento
        detalleparser =  DetalleParser.new
        arrayDocumentos = Array.new

        #Se abre el archivo CSV en modo lectura, con el separador de filas automático
        #el de columnas como pipe, las líneas en blanco se omiten
        CSV.open(archivo, 'r', :row_sep => :auto, :col_sep => '|', :skip_blanks => :true, :quote_char => "\"").each do |row|
            Rails.logger.debug "DOCUMENTO: #{row}"
            #Si existe la fila como un array y el conteo de este es mayor a cero
            #se inicia el parseo
            if row && row.count > 0
                Rails.logger.debug "CONTEO: #{row.count}"
                Rails.logger.debug "Entró a cabecera: #{row[0].start_with?("E01")}"
                Rails.logger.debug "Entró a detalle1: #{row[0].start_with?("D01")}"
                Rails.logger.debug "Entró a detalle2: #{row[0].start_with?("D02")}"
                Rails.logger.debug "Entró a Impuestos: #{row[0].start_with?("I01")}"
                Rails.logger.debug "Entró a notas de crédito: #{row[0].start_with?("E98")}"
                Rails.logger.debug "Entró a totales: #{row[0].start_with?("T01")}"

                #Si el array fila en su posición cero inicia con "E01" se inicia con el
                #proceso de parseo de los datos de cabecera
                if row[0].start_with?("E01")
                    # ============================================================================
                    # Línea 1 (ENCABEZADO)
                    # ============================================================================
                    #Se crea un array donde se almacenarán los datos de cabecera del archivo
                    #encabezado = Array.new
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO DTE #{row[3]} =================="
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO ENCABEZADO =================="

                    #Se asigna al array encabezado el contenido de la fila
                    encabezado << row

                    #mapeo de los campos de encabezado
                    identificador_cabecera = encabezado[0][0]
                    tipo_documento = encabezado[0][1]
                    serie = encabezado[0][2]
                    numero_documento = encabezado[0][3]
                    tipo_foliacion = encabezado[0][4]
                    id_interno = encabezado[0][5]
                    fecha_emision = encabezado[0][6]
                    estado_documento = encabezado[0][7]
                    fecha_anulacion = encabezado[0][8]
                    nreg_tipo2 = encabezado[0][9]
                    nreg_tipo3 = encabezado[0][10]
                    nit_vendedor = encabezado[0][11]
                    codigo_establecimiento = encabezado[0][12]
                    nit_comprador = encabezado[0][13]
                    nombre_comprador = encabezado[0][14]
                    codglobal_receptor = encabezado[0][15]
                    direccion_comprador = encabezado[0][16]
                    municipio_comprador = encabezado[0][17]
                    departamento_comprador = encabezado[0][18]
                    pais_comprador = encabezado[0][19]
                    telefono_comprador = encabezado[0][20]
                    direccion_envio = encabezado[0][21]
                    municipio_envio = encabezado[0][22]
                    departamento_envio = encabezado[0][23]
                    pais_envio = encabezado[0][24]
                    codigo_moneda = encabezado[0][25]
                    tipo_cambio = encabezado[0][26]
                    regimenISR = encabezado[0][27]
                    total_bruto = encabezado[0][28]
                    total_descuento = encabezado[0][29]
                    total_exento = encabezado[0][30]
                    total_neto = encabezado[0][31]
                    totalIVA = encabezado[0][32]
                    total_otros_impuetos = encabezado[0][33]
                    total_general = encabezado[0][34]
                    total_en_letras = encabezado[0][35]
                    id_plantilla = encabezado[0][36]
                    id_receptor = encabezado[0][37]

                    Rails.logger.debug "ENCABEZADO: #{encabezado.to_s}"
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== FIN ENCABEZADO =================="
                #Si el array fila en su posición cero inicia con "D01" se inicia con el
                #proceso de parseo de los datos de descripción de los detalles
                elsif row[0].start_with?("D01")
                    # ============================================================================
                    # Línea 2 (DETALLE - DESCRIPCIÓN) 
                    # ============================================================================
                    #Se crea un array donde se almacenarán los datos de descripción de los detalles
                    #detalle_descripcion = Array.new
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO DETALLE DESCRIPCION =================="

                    #Se asigna al array detalle_descripcion el contenido de la fila
                    detalle_descripcion << row

                    #mapeo de campos de descripción del detalle
                    identificador_detalle_uno = detalle_descripcion[0][0]
                    tipo_codigo = detalle_descripcion[0][1]
                    codigo = detalle_descripcion[0][2]
                    descripcion = detalle_descripcion[0][3]
                    cantidad = detalle_descripcion[0][4]
                    bien_servicio = detalle_descripcion[0][5]
                    unidad_medida = detalle_descripcion[0][6]
                    precio_unitario = detalle_descripcion[0][7]
                    porcentaje_descuento = detalle_descripcion[0][8]
                    importe_descuento = detalle_descripcion[0][9]
                    importe_bruto = detalle_descripcion[0][10]
                    importe_exento = detalle_descripcion[0][11]
                    importe_neto = detalle_descripcion[0][12]
                    importeIVA = detalle_descripcion[0][13]

                    Rails.logger.debug "DETALLE1: #{detalle_descripcion.to_s}"
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== FIN DETALLE DESCRIPCION =================="
                #Si el array fila en su posición cero inicia con "D02" se inicia con el
                #proceso de parseo de los datos de impuestos de los detalles
                elsif row[0].start_with?("D02")
                    # ============================================================================
                    # Línea 3 (DETALLE - IMPUESTOS)
                    # ============================================================================
                    #Se crea un array donde se almacenarán los datos de impuestos de los detalles
                    #detalle_impuestos = Array.new
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO DETALLE IMPUESTOS =================="

                    #Se asigna al array detalle_impuestos el contenido de la fila
                    detalle_impuestos << row

                    #mapeo de campos de impuestos del detalle
                    identificador_detalle_dos = detalle_impuestos[0][0]
                    tipo_impuesto_detalle = detalle_impuestos[0][1]
                    monto_afecto_detalle = detalle_impuestos[0][2]
                    monto_impuesto_detalle = detalle_impuestos[0][3]
                    porcentaje_impuesto_detalle = detalle_impuestos[0][4]

                    Rails.logger.debug "DETALLE2: #{detalle_impuestos.to_s}"
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== FIN DETALLE IMPUESTOS =================="
                #Si el array fila en su posición cero inicia con "E98" se inicia con el
                #proceso de parseo de los datos de nota de crédito
                elsif row[0].start_with?("E98")
                    # ============================================================================
                    # Línea 4 opcional (DOCUMENTO ORIGEN - solo NCE)
                    # ============================================================================
                    #Se crea un array donde se almacenarán los datos de nota de crédito
                    #documento_origen = Array.new
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO DATOS NCE =================="

                    #Se asigna al array documento_origen el contenido de la fila
                    documento_origen << row

                    #mapeo de campos de nota de crédito
                    identificador_nota = documento_origen[0][0]
                    tipo_nota = documento_origen[0][1]
                    campo_vacio = documento_origen[0][2]
                    descripcion_nota = documento_origen[0][3]

                    Rails.logger.debug "NCE: #{documento_origen.to_s}"
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== FIN DATOS NCE =================="
                #Si el array fila en su posición cero inicia con "I01" se inicia con el
                #proceso de parseo de los datos de impuestos a nivel de totales
                elsif row[0].start_with?("I01")
                    # ============================================================================
                    # Línea 5 (IMPUESTOS)
                    # ============================================================================
                    #Se crea un array donde se almacenarán los datos de impuestos a nivel de totales
                    #impuestos = Array.new
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO IMPUESTOS =================="

                    #Se asigna al array impuestos el contenido de la fila
                    impuestos << row

                    #mapeo de campos de impuestos a nivel de totales
                    identificador_totales = impuestos[0][0]
                    tipo_impuesto_totales = impuestos[0][1]
                    monto_afecto_totales = impuestos[0][2]
                    monto_impuesto_totales = impuestos[0][3]
                    porcentaje_impuesto_totales = impuestos[0][4]

                    Rails.logger.debug "IMPUESTOS: #{impuestos.to_s}"
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== FIN IMPUESTOS =================="
                    Rails.logger.debug "===================== FIN DTE ====================="
                #Si el array fila en su posición cero inicia con "T01" se inicia con el
                #proceso de parseo de los datos de documentos
                elsif row[0].start_with?("T01")
                    # ============================================================================
                    # Línea Final (TOTALES - ARCHIVO)
                    # ============================================================================
                    #Se crea un array donde se almacenarán los datos de totales del archivo
                    #totales = Array.new
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO TOTALES ARCHIVO =================="

                    #Se asigna al array totales el contenido de la fila
                    totales << row

                    #mapeo de los campos de totales de archivo
                    identificador_archivo = totales[0][0]
                    folio_inicial = totales[0][1]
                    folio_final = totales[0][2]
                    total_documentos = totales[0][3]
                    id_lote = totales[0][4]

                    Rails.logger.debug "TOTALES: #{totales.to_s}"
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== FIN TOTALES ARCHIVO =================="
                end

                dteparser.numero_documento = numero_documento
                dteparser.fecha_documento = fecha_emision
                dteparser.fecha_anulacion = fecha_anulacion
                dteparser.estado_documento = estado_documento
                dteparser.codigo_moneda = codigo_moneda
                dteparser.tipo_cambio = tipo_cambio
                dteparser.observaciones = "N/A"
                dteparser.regimen_isr =  regimenISR
                dteparser.nit_comprador = nit_comprador
                dteparser.nombre_comprador = nombre_comprador
                dteparser.direccion_comprador = direccion_comprador
                dteparser.correo_comprador = "N/A"
                dteparser.telefono_comprador =  telefono_comprador
                dteparser.regimen_2989 =  "2"
                dteparser.municipio_comprador = municipio_comprador
                dteparser.departamento_comprador = departamento_comprador
                dteparser.nit_vendedor = nit_vendedor
                dteparser.nombre_vendedor = "DEMO" #pendiente
                dteparser.direccion_vendedor = "CIUDAD" #pendiente
                dteparser.correo_vendedor =  "N/A" #pendiente
                dteparser.telefono_vendedor =  "N/A" #pendiente
                dteparser.municipio_vendedor = municipio_vendedor
                dteparser.departamento_vendedor = departamento_vendedor
                dteparser.codigo_establecimiento =  codigo_establecimiento
                dteparser.id_dispositivo =  "0" #pendiente
                dteparser.serie_autorizada = serie
                dteparser.numero_resolucion = numero_resolucion #pendiente
                dteparser.fecha_resolucion = fecha_resolucion #pendiente
                dteparser.tipo_documento = tipo_documento
                dteparser.serie_documento =  prefijo_serie #pendiente
                dteparser.nit_gface = "12521337"
                dteparser.importe_bruto = total_bruto
                dteparser.detalle_impuestos_iva = totalIVA
                dteparser.importe_neto_gravado = total_neto
                dteparser.importe_descuento = total_descuento
                dteparser.importe_total_exento = total_exento
                dteparser.importe_otros_impuestos = total_otros_impuetos
                dteparser.monto_total_operacion = total_general
                dteparser.descripcion_otro_impuesto =  "N/A"
                dteparser.personalizado_01 = "N/A"
                dteparser.personalizado_02 = tipo_foliacion
                dteparser.personalizado_03 = id_interno
                dteparser.personalizado_04 = nreg_tipo2
                dteparser.personalizado_05 = nreg_tipo3
                dteparser.personalizado_06 = codglobal_receptor
                dteparser.personalizado_07 = id_plantilla
                dteparser.personalizado_08 = id_receptor
                dteparser.personalizado_09 = "N/A"
                dteparser.personalizado_10 = "N/A"
                dteparser.personalizado_11 = "N/A"
                dteparser.personalizado_12 = "N/A"
                dteparser.personalizado_13 = "N/A"
                dteparser.personalizado_14 = "N/A"
                dteparser.personalizado_15 = "N/A"
                dteparser.personalizado_16 = "N/A"
                dteparser.personalizado_17 = "N/A"
                dteparser.personalizado_18 = "N/A"
                dteparser.personalizado_19 = "N/A"
                dteparser.personalizado_20 = "N/A"

                detalleparser.cantidad = cantidad
                detalleparser.codigo_producto = codigo
                detalleparser.descripcion_producto = descripcion
                detalleparser.precio_unitario =  precio_unitario
                detalleparser.monto_bruto = importe_bruto
                detalleparser.detalle_impuestos_iva = importeIVA
                detalleparser.importe_neto_gravado = importe_neto
                detalleparser.monto_descuento = importe_descuento
                detalleparser.importe_exento = importe_exento
                detalleparser.importe_otros_impuestos = 0.00
                detalleparser.importe_total_operacion = importe_neto
                detalleparser.unidad_medida = unidad_medida
                detalleparser.tipo_producto = bien_servicio
                detalleparser.personalizado_01 = porcentaje_descuento
                detalleparser.personalizado_02 = tipo_codigo
                detalleparser.personalizado_03 = "N/A"
                detalleparser.personalizado_04 = "N/A"
                detalleparser.personalizado_05 = "N/A"
                detalleparser.personalizado_06 = "N/A"

                dteparser.detalles_dte.push (detalleparser)
            end #Fin IF row && row.count > 0
            dteparser.save
        end #Fin Each
        arrayDocumentos.push (dteparser)
        Rails.logger.debug "cabecera: #{cabecera}"
        Rails.logger.debug "detalle1: #{detalle_descripcion}"
        Rails.logger.debug "detalle2: #{detalle_impuestos}"
        Rails.logger.debug "Impuestos: #{impuestos}"
        Rails.logger.debug "notas de crédito: #{documento_origen}"
        Rails.logger.debug "totales: #{totales}"
        puts "==================== FIN ARCHIVO ===================="

        respuesta = {resultado: true, data: arrayDocumentos}

        return respuesta
    rescue Exception => e
        respuesta = {resultado: false, data: e.message}
    end #Fin Método
end #Fin Clase
```

De antemano agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Saludos

Comment: No me queda claro el problema; ¿podrías poner el _output_ esperado del fragmento que muestras del CSV?

Comment: Con gusto, sin embargo no es un output como tal, ya que para pruebas de testing el "output" es el esperado, lo que pasa es que necesito pasar los valores extraídos de cada línea que están separados por pipes en variables y/o atributos para crear un objeto de otra clase, he logrado obtener el output correcto, pero este debo de colocarlo en un objeto de otra clase, si aún no es suficiente información con gusto amplío, adicional es de un proyecto de ruby on rails, por eso la etiqueta que había colocado

Comment: Concuerdo con @Gerry que no está claro lo que necesitas. Actualmente estás asignando los valores de las filas en los objetos, así que lo que preguntas cómo hacer ya lo estás haciendo. ¿no te está guardando correctamente los valores? ¿algunas líneas se guardan y otras no? ¿algunos campos son guardados y otros no?. Como consejo, te sugeriría que hagas un refactoring de tu código, modularizarlo más. Para cualquiera es difícil depurar un método de más de 300 líneas, así también enfocar la pregunta en qué es lo que retorna **actualmente** y que es lo que **esperas** que retorne

Comment: Otro consejo aparte, revisa porque nunca es bueno hacer un [`rescue Exception => e`](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rescue-standarderror-not-exception). No creo que sea la causa de tu problema, pero puede evitarte dolores de cabeza a futuro. Saludos

Comment: Estoy muy cerca de lograr mi objetivo, en cuanto tenga la respuesta la publico

Saludos

Comment: Cambié el título porque tenían razón, no era el adecuado según mi consulta,

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de todo, muchas gracias a quienes se tomaron la molestia de pasar y tratar de ayudarme, les comento que logré solventar mi problema, les comparto el código:

```
require 'csv'

class ConversionTxtMegaprint

    #Método para parsear los TXT
    def procesar_archivo (archivo)

        Rails.logger.debug "================================= INICIO ARCHIVO ===================================="
        Rails.logger.debug ""
        Rails.logger.debug "---> NOMBRE ARCHIVO: " + archivo
        Rails.logger.debug ""

        encabezado = nil
        detalle_descripcion = nil
        detalle_impuestos = nil
        impuestos = nil
        documento_origen = nil
        totales = nil

        # Se crea el objeto dteparser para establecer los valores del documento (cabecera y detalle), los datos
        # para llenar este objeto se tomaran del hash que es donde esta reunida toda la informacion.
        dteparser = nil
        # Se crea un nuevo objeto por cada detalle que encuentre relacionado al documento
        detalleparser =  nil
        arrayDocumentos = Array.new

        #Se abre el archivo CSV en modo lectura, con el separador de filas automático
        #el de columnas como pipe, las líneas en blanco se omiten
        CSV.open(archivo, 'r', :row_sep => :auto, :col_sep => '|', :skip_blanks => :true, :quote_char => "\"").each do |row|
            ##Rails.logger.debug "FILA: #{row}"
            #Si existe la fila como un array y el conteo de este es mayor a cero
            #se inicia el parseo
            if row && row.count > 0
                Rails.logger.debug "CONTEO: #{row.count}"
                Rails.logger.debug "Entró a cabecera: #{row[0].start_with?("E01")}"
                Rails.logger.debug "Entró a detalle1: #{row[0].start_with?("D01")}"
                Rails.logger.debug "Entró a detalle2: #{row[0].start_with?("D02")}"
                Rails.logger.debug "Entró a Impuestos: #{row[0].start_with?("I01")}"
                Rails.logger.debug "Entró a notas de crédito: #{row[0].start_with?("E98")}"
                Rails.logger.debug "Entró a totales: #{row[0].start_with?("T01")}"

                #Si el array fila en su posición cero inicia con "E01" se inicia con el
                #proceso de parseo de los datos de cabecera
                if row[0].start_with?("E01")
                    # ============================================================================
                    # Línea 1 (ENCABEZADO)
                    # ============================================================================
                    #Se crea un array donde se almacenarán los datos de cabecera del archivo
                    encabezado = Array.new
                    dteparser = DteParser.new
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO DTE #{row[3]} =================="
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO ENCABEZADO =================="

                    efaces = Eface.where("nit_vendedor = ? ", row[11].gsub("-","")).first
                    eface = efaces.id_eface
                    razon_social = efaces.razon_social
                    direccion_eface = efaces.direccion_comercial
                    correo_eface = efaces.email_empresa

                    series = Serie.where("id_eface = ? and serie = ? and status = ? ", eface, row[2], "A")
                    Rails.logger.debug "SERIE: #{series.to_json}"

                    if series.count == 1
                        serie = series.first

                        resolucion = serie.numero_resolucion
                        fecha_autorizacion = serie.fecha_autorizacion.to_s
                        codigo_sat = serie.codigo_sat.to_i.to_s
                        dispositivo = serie.establecimiento.dispositivos.where("id_dispositivo = 0").first.id_dispositivo

                        #Se asigna al array encabezado el contenido de la fila
                        encabezado << row

                        #mapeo de los datos de encabezado
                        dteparser.numero_documento = encabezado[0][3] if encabezado[0][3]
                        dteparser.fecha_documento = encabezado[0][6] if encabezado[0][6]
                        dteparser.fecha_anulacion = encabezado[0][8] if encabezado[0][8]
                        dteparser.estado_documento = encabezado[0][7] if encabezado[0][7]
                        dteparser.codigo_moneda = encabezado[0][25] if encabezado[0][25]
                        dteparser.tipo_cambio = encabezado[0][26] if encabezado[0][26]
                        dteparser.observaciones = "N/A"
                        dteparser.regimen_isr =  encabezado[0][27] if encabezado[0][27]
                        dteparser.nit_comprador = encabezado[0][13] if encabezado[0][13]
                        dteparser.nombre_comprador = encabezado[0][14] if encabezado[0][14]
                        dteparser.direccion_comprador = encabezado[0][16] if encabezado[0][16]
                        dteparser.correo_comprador = "N/A"
                        dteparser.telefono_comprador =  encabezado[0][20] if encabezado[0][20] ||="N/A"
                        dteparser.regimen_2989 =  "2"
                        dteparser.municipio_comprador = encabezado[0][17] if encabezado[0][17] ||="GUATEMALA"
                        dteparser.departamento_comprador = encabezado[0][18] if encabezado[0][18] ||="GUATEMALA"
                        dteparser.nit_vendedor = encabezado[0][11].gsub("-","") if encabezado[0][11]
                        dteparser.nombre_vendedor = razon_social
                        dteparser.direccion_vendedor = direccion_eface
                        dteparser.correo_vendedor =  correo_eface ||="N/A"
                        dteparser.telefono_vendedor =  "N/A"
                        dteparser.municipio_vendedor = encabezado[0][22] if encabezado[0][22] ||="GUATEMALA"
                        dteparser.departamento_vendedor = encabezado[0][23] if encabezado[0][23] ||="GUATEMALA"
                        dteparser.codigo_establecimiento =  encabezado[0][12] if encabezado[0][12]
                        dteparser.id_dispositivo =  dispositivo
                        dteparser.serie_autorizada = encabezado[0][2] if encabezado[0][2]
                        dteparser.numero_resolucion = resolucion
                        dteparser.fecha_resolucion = fecha_autorizacion #"2017-09-01" #pendiente
                        dteparser.tipo_documento = encabezado[0][1] if encabezado[0][1]
                        dteparser.serie_documento = codigo_sat
                        dteparser.nit_gface = "12521337"
                        dteparser.detalle_impuestos_iva = encabezado[0][32] if encabezado[0][32]
                        dteparser.importe_neto_gravado = encabezado[0][34] if encabezado[0][34]
                        dteparser.importe_bruto = (dteparser.importe_neto_gravado.to_f - dteparser.detalle_impuestos_iva.to_f).round(2) if encabezado[0][32] && encabezado[0][34] ||= encabezado[0][34]
                        dteparser.importe_descuento = encabezado[0][29] if encabezado[0][29]
                        dteparser.importe_total_exento = encabezado[0][30] if encabezado[0][30]
                        dteparser.importe_otros_impuestos = encabezado[0][33] if encabezado[0][33]
                        dteparser.monto_total_operacion = encabezado[0][34] if encabezado[0][34]
                        dteparser.descripcion_otro_impuesto =  "N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_01 = "N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_02 = encabezado[0][4] if encabezado[0][4]
                        dteparser.personalizado_03 = encabezado[0][5] if encabezado[0][5] ||="N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_04 = encabezado[0][9] if encabezado[0][9] ||="N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_05 = encabezado[0][10] if encabezado[0][10] ||="N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_06 = encabezado[0][15] if encabezado[0][15] ||="N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_07 = encabezado[0][36] if encabezado[0][36] ||="N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_08 = encabezado[0][37] if encabezado[0][37] ||="N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_09 = "N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_10 = "N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_11 = "N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_12 = "N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_13 = "N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_14 = "N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_15 = "N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_16 = "N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_17 = "N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_18 = "N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_19 = "N/A"
                        dteparser.personalizado_20 = "N/A"
                    end

                    #Rails.logger.debug "ENCABEZADO: #{encabezado.to_s}"
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== FIN ENCABEZADO =================="
                end
                #Si el array fila en su posición cero inicia con "D01" se inicia con el
                #proceso de parseo de los datos de descripción de los detalles
                if row[0].start_with?("D01")
                    # ============================================================================
                    # Línea 2 (DETALLE - DESCRIPCIÓN) 
                    # ============================================================================
                    #Se crea un array donde se almacenarán los datos de descripción de los detalles
                    detalle_descripcion = Array.new
                    detalleparser =  DetalleParser.new
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO DETALLE DESCRIPCION =================="

                    #Se asigna al array detalle_descripcion el contenido de la fila
                    detalle_descripcion << row


                    #mapeo de campos de descripción del detalle
                    numero_documento_detalle = encabezado[0][3]
                    detalleparser.cantidad = detalle_descripcion[0][4] if detalle_descripcion[0][4]
                    detalleparser.codigo_producto = detalle_descripcion[0][2] if detalle_descripcion[0][2]
                    detalleparser.descripcion_producto = detalle_descripcion[0][3] if detalle_descripcion[0][3]
                    detalleparser.precio_unitario =  detalle_descripcion[0][7] if detalle_descripcion[0][7]
                    detalleparser.monto_bruto = detalle_descripcion[0][12] if detalle_descripcion[0][12]
                    detalleparser.detalle_impuestos_iva = detalle_descripcion[0][13] if detalle_descripcion[0][13]
                    detalleparser.importe_neto_gravado = detalle_descripcion[0][10] if detalle_descripcion[0][10]
                    detalleparser.monto_descuento = detalle_descripcion[0][9] if detalle_descripcion[0][9]
                    detalleparser.importe_exento = detalle_descripcion[0][11] if detalle_descripcion[0][11]
                    detalleparser.importe_otros_impuestos = 0.00
                    detalleparser.importe_total_operacion = detalle_descripcion[0][10] if detalle_descripcion[0][10]
                    detalleparser.unidad_medida = detalle_descripcion[0][6] if detalle_descripcion[0][6]
                    detalleparser.tipo_producto = detalle_descripcion[0][5] if detalle_descripcion[0][5]
                    detalleparser.personalizado_01 = detalle_descripcion[0][8] if detalle_descripcion[0][8] ||="N/A"
                    detalleparser.personalizado_02 = detalle_descripcion[0][1] if detalle_descripcion[0][1] ||="N/A"
                    detalleparser.personalizado_03 = "N/A"
                    detalleparser.personalizado_04 = "N/A"
                    detalleparser.personalizado_05 = "N/A"
                    detalleparser.personalizado_06 = "N/A"

                    dteparser.detalles_dte.push (detalleparser)
                    arrayDocumentos.push (dteparser)
                    #Rails.logger.debug "DETALLE1: #{detalle_descripcion.to_s}"
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== FIN DETALLE DESCRIPCION =================="
                end
                #Si el array fila en su posición cero inicia con "D02" se inicia con el
                #proceso de parseo de los datos de impuestos de los detalles
                if row[0].start_with?("D02")
                    # ============================================================================
                    # Línea 3 (DETALLE - IMPUESTOS)
                    # ============================================================================
                    #Se crea un array donde se almacenarán los datos de impuestos de los detalles
                    detalle_impuestos = Array.new
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO DETALLE IMPUESTOS =================="

                    #Se asigna al array detalle_impuestos el contenido de la fila
                    detalle_impuestos << row

                    #mapeo de campos de impuestos del detalle
                    identificador_detalle_dos = detalle_impuestos[0][0]
                    tipo_impuesto_detalle = detalle_impuestos[0][1]
                    monto_afecto_detalle = detalle_impuestos[0][2]
                    monto_impuesto_detalle = detalle_impuestos[0][3]
                    porcentaje_impuesto_detalle = detalle_impuestos[0][4]

                    #Rails.logger.debug "DETALLE2: #{detalle_impuestos.to_s}"
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== FIN DETALLE IMPUESTOS =================="
                end
                #Si el array fila en su posición cero inicia con "E98" se inicia con el
                #proceso de parseo de los datos de nota de crédito
                if row[0].start_with?("E98")
                    # ============================================================================
                    # Línea 4 opcional (DOCUMENTO ORIGEN - solo NCE)
                    # ============================================================================
                    #Se crea un array donde se almacenarán los datos de nota de crédito
                    documento_origen = Array.new
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO DATOS NCE =================="

                    #Se asigna al array documento_origen el contenido de la fila
                    documento_origen << row

                    #mapeo de campos de nota de crédito
                    identificador_nota = documento_origen[0][0]
                    tipo_nota = documento_origen[0][1]
                    campo_vacio = documento_origen[0][2]
                    descripcion_nota = documento_origen[0][3]

                    #Rails.logger.debug "NCE: #{documento_origen.to_s}"
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== FIN DATOS NCE =================="
                end
                #Si el array fila en su posición cero inicia con "I01" se inicia con el
                #proceso de parseo de los datos de impuestos a nivel de totales
                if row[0].start_with?("I01")
                    # ============================================================================
                    # Línea 5 (IMPUESTOS)
                    # ============================================================================
                    #Se crea un array donde se almacenarán los datos de impuestos a nivel de totales
                    impuestos = Array.new
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO IMPUESTOS =================="

                    #Se asigna al array impuestos el contenido de la fila
                    impuestos << row

                    #mapeo de campos de impuestos a nivel de totales
                    identificador_totales = impuestos[0][0]
                    tipo_impuesto_totales = impuestos[0][1]
                    monto_afecto_totales = impuestos[0][2]
                    monto_impuesto_totales = impuestos[0][3]
                    porcentaje_impuesto_totales = impuestos[0][4]

                    #Rails.logger.debug "IMPUESTOS: #{impuestos.to_s}"
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== FIN IMPUESTOS =================="
                    Rails.logger.debug "===================== FIN DTE ====================="
                end
                #Si el array fila en su posición cero inicia con "T01" se inicia con el
                #proceso de parseo de los datos de documentos
                if row[0].start_with?("T01")
                    # ============================================================================
                    # Línea Final (TOTALES - ARCHIVO)
                    # ============================================================================
                    #Se crea un array donde se almacenarán los datos de totales del archivo
                    totales = Array.new
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== INICIO TOTALES ARCHIVO =================="

                    #Se asigna al array totales el contenido de la fila
                    totales << row

                    #mapeo de los campos de totales de archivo
                    identificador_archivo = totales[0][0]
                    folio_inicial = totales[0][1]
                    folio_final = totales[0][2]
                    total_documentos = totales[0][3]
                    id_lote = totales[0][4]

                    #Rails.logger.debug "TOTALES: #{totales.to_s}"
                    Rails.logger.debug "================== FIN TOTALES ARCHIVO =================="
                end
            end #Fin IF row && row.count > 0
            #arrayDocumentos.push (dteparser)
        end #Fin Each
        Rails.logger.debug "FIN DE PARSEO"
        ##Rails.logger.debug "cabecera: #{encabezado}"
        ##Rails.logger.debug "detalle1: #{detalle_descripcion}"
        ##Rails.logger.debug "detalle2: #{detalle_impuestos}"
        ##Rails.logger.debug "Impuestos: #{impuestos}"
        ##Rails.logger.debug "notas de crédito: #{documento_origen}"
        ##Rails.logger.debug "totales: #{totales}"
        Rails.logger.debug "==================== FIN ARCHIVO ===================="

        respuesta = {resultado: true, data: arrayDocumentos}

        return respuesta
    rescue Exception => e
        respuesta = {resultado: false, data: e.message}
    end #Fin Método
end #Fin Clase
```

Al final lo que hice fue que los objetos que necesitaba llenar los coloqué en los IF donde iba recorriendo el archivo y luego hacía un push al array final, esto lo pasaba a la otra clase y listo

Answer (score 1):

no soy muy bueno con ruby pero puede que esto te sirva

```
# encoding: UTF-8
f = File.open(archivo, "r")
a = ""
b = ""
f.each_line do |line|
  nn = line.gsub(/\s+/, "|").strip
  nnl = nn.gsub /^$|/, ''
  nl = nn.split("|")
    nl.each do |lines|
        if not lines ==""
                a+= lines+","
        end
    end
    tmp = a[0...-1]
   b += tmp+"\n"
end
puts b
f.close
```

ahora ya lo podras trajar como un csv

Comment: Voy a explorar la respuesta que me has brindado y en cuanto pueda te respondo, muchas gracias

Comment: Te comento que probé tu código sin embargo no era lo que necesitaba, pero siempre gracias, encontré la respuesta y ahora la publico